# convert number to word in Iphone

Tags: ios4

Hi any Body give me an idea how to convert a number to word.

For exm:- if number is 100 the word must be one hundred.

if number is 250 then word will be two hundred fifty etc.

If i give any input of a number then the corresponding word of out will be print in console.

Thanks
jay

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString*)numberToWord:(NSInteger)number {

           NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
           [formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
           return  [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:number]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a Java program that converts any Integer type number (byte, short, int and even long !) into words.

This value goes into pentillions
`One pentillion = 1000000 trillion`
both in negative and positive, including zero.

Here you go :

```
package Practice.Program;

public class Num2Words {
  
  private static long number;
  private static String words = new String("");
  
  public Num2Words(long n){ number = n; }
  
  static String[] tp = {"", "thousand ", "million ", "billion ", "trillion ", "quadrillion ", "pentillion "};
  static String[] od = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
  static String[] td = {"ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
  static String[] tn = {"", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
  
  public String toWords(){
    words = Long.toString(number);
    int l = words.length();
    boolean n = false;
    
    if (number < 0){ n = true; number *= -1; --l;}
    
    breaker : for (byte LOL = 0; LOL < 1; LOL++){
      
      if (StringHasChar(words, '.')){ words = "Decimals not supported."; break breaker;}
      if (l>19){ words = "too big"; break breaker;}
      
      if (l==1)      words = oneDigit(number);                    // one digit
      
      else if (l==2) words = twoDigits(number);                   // two digits 
      
      else if (l==3) words = threeDigits(number);                 // three digits
      
      else words = nDigits(number);                               // multiple digits
      
    }
    
    if (n == true) {words = "Minus "+words; number *= -1;}
   return words;
  }
  
  private static String oneDigit(long n){
    char[] ns = Long.toString(n).toCharArray();
    return od[(char2num(ns[0]))];
  }
  
  private static String twoDigits(long n){
    String s = "";
    char[] ns = Long.toString(n).toCharArray();
    if (n < 20){
      s = td[(char2num(ns[1]))];
    } else if (n < 100){
        s = tn[char2num(ns[0])];
        if (char2num(ns[1])!=0){ s += " " + od[char2num(ns[1])]; }
      }
    return s;
  }
  
  private static String threeDigits(long n){
    String s = "", is = Long.toString(n);
    long[] ns = String2longArray(is);
    
    s = od[(int)(ns[0])] + " hundred";
    if (ns[1]!=0&&ns[2]!=0){
      long i = (ns[1])*10+(ns[2]);
      s += " " + twoDigits(i);
    } else {
        if (ns[1]!=0) s += " " + twoDigits((ns[1]*10)); 
        if (ns[2]!=0) s += " " + oneDigit(ns[2]);
      }
    
    return s;
  }
  
  private static String nDigits(long n){
    String s = threeDigits(n);
    int tpi = ((digits(n)+2)/3)-1, rtpi = 0;
    long[] tfr = threeFromRight(n);
    s = "";
    
    for (; tpi >= 0; tpi--, rtpi++){
      s = new Num2Words(tfr[tpi]).toWords() + " " + tp[rtpi] + s;
    }
    
    return s;
  }
  
  private static int digits(long n){
    long ans = 0;
    for (; n>0; n/=10, ans++);
    return (int)(ans);
  }
  
  private static long[] threeFromRight(long n){
    int tpi = (digits(n)+2)/3, nl = digits(n);
    long[] ans=new long[tpi], ia=String2longArray(Long.toString(n)), ta=new long[3];
    
    for (int i=nl, t=2, c=0, l=tpi*3; l >= 0; l--, c++, i--, t--){
      try {ta[t] = ia[i-1];}
      catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){ta[t]=0;}
      if (((c+1)%3)==0){ 
        --tpi;
        ans[tpi] = longArrays2long(ta);
        
        t = 3;
        c = -1;
      }
    }
    
    return ans;
  }
  
  private static int char2num(char c){
    char[] ca = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    byte ia[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},  ans = -1;
    
    for (byte i = 0; i < 10; i++){ if (c == ca[i]){ ans = ia[i]; break;} }
    return ans;
  }
  
  private static long[] String2longArray(String s){
    char[] ca = s.toCharArray();
    byte l = (byte)s.length();
    long[] ans = new long[l];
    
    for (byte i = 0; i < l; i++){ ans[i] = char2num(ca[i]); }
    return ans;
  }
  
  private static long longArrays2long(long[] ia){
    long ans = 0;
    try { for (int i = 0; i >= 0; ans += ia[i], ans *= 10, ++i); } 
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
    ans/=10;
    
    return ans;
  }
  
  private static boolean StringHasChar(String s, char c){
    char[] sca = s.toCharArray();
    byte l = (byte)(s.length());
    boolean ans = false;
    for (byte i = 0; i > l; i++){
      if (sca[i] == c) ans = true;
    }
    return ans;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args){
    long n = -1053664648543756767l;
    String words = new Num2Words(n).toWords();
    
    System.out.println(n + " : " + words);
  }
  
}
```

`Note` : The `main(String[] args)` is only for testing purposes. You may, or may not include it in your code.